# Installing Qt SDK, cannot link to the C++ libraries

Tags: qt

So I have installed the QtSDK on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. However, it seems like when I try to run a simple program like hello world such as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(....) {
     std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

My program first gets the error:
CreateProcess: No Such file or directory.

So what I did was I went to this link here:
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_MinGW_with_Vista

And I first tried to add the directory to the

```
PATH: C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\MinGW-Version
```

(my directory is slightly different but follows same idea) 
where MinGW-Version is the Version of MinGW you are using

So now that got rid of that error but now I get the error:
iostream: No such file or directory

So now I add the path where the iostream library is and that fixes that error but then I get all these other errors where it can't find other standard C++ libraries such as stddef.h or stdio.h etc. So it seems as if the C++ libraries cannot be linked to. I have tried various other things such as including `C:\MinGW\bin` in my path and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Qt. Also I have checked that Qt is using the right gcc compiler by going to Tools->Options->Toolchains in Qt Creator.

It seems that the linking to C++ libraries is not correct for some reason. Could anyone help me or guide me as to why this may be happening and how to fix this?

Comment: What exact Qt intaller did you use? Is it really for mingw, and not msvc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working, so I'll just tell you how my environment is set up.  I don't think you need to add any library paths to the system path.  You should only need to add C:\MinGW\bin.

So get rid of everything except for that.  Also, are you setting this through cmd or control panel?  If doing it in the control panel, make sure you are putting it in the "Path" variable not "PATH" -> the former is in the lower box.  I've had problems before using "PATH" in the upper box - not sure what the difference is to be honest.

Comment: Hi Buck, I have tried that but it doesn't help. I am still stuck at where I am. I made sure I updated Path. It seems for me though that Path and PATH are the same atleast when I check in the command prompt

Comment: According to Qt, if I go to Tools -> Options then click tool chains I am using MinGW specifically g++.exe in the directory C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\g++.exe. Is this the right command to compile?

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator?  Try this, in the directory where you have saved your "Hello world" program, open a command prompt and try to compile without Qt.  Just do `g++ -o program filename.cpp` and see if that compiles

Answer (score 0):

The QtSDK installation usually install the mingw compiler for you in ...\QtSDK\mingw. The libraries and dlls in ...\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.3\mingw were compiled with this compiler. The mingw compiler you installed to c:\MinGW may be a different version than that. If you want to use this compiler you would have to recompile the Qt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

C++ librairies in Qt.
Go to this URL http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-overview.html for how to.
It seems (I did not try it, yet) that other librairies can be easily linked to a Qt Project.
This could solve the problem.

Pythagooric